# Why is the plural 'oxen'? Is it acceptable to use 'oxes'?

Tags: grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

According to a English grammar rules, we add 'es' when the noun ends with 's', 'ss', 'sh', 'x', or 'ch'. With these rules, 'ox' would become 'oxes' in the plural.

Can 'oxes' be used as the plural of 'ox'?

Comment: English has many irregular nouns. They don't follow the rules.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Plurals_in_-(e)n

Comment: A minor, but crucial, clarification of what Lambie said above: *all* English words do follow rules. But not all English words follow the same *set* of rules. "Oxen" is formed according to a clear rule. It's just that we don't apply that rule for new words anymore. Also note that this has nothing to do with grammar. Grammar rules only tell you when to use plural and when to use singular, but what that plural or singular actually looks like is governed by morphology and not grammar. We could change the plural from *-s* to *-ü* overnight and it would not affect a single rule of English grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very old word, Old or Middle English, and is irregular, like "child and children", and hasn't changed over the centuries. This ending -en on a noun is very rare. You can't say "oxes".

Comment: Welcome John H. The system has flagged your answer as "low-quality because of its length and content." An answer on EL&U is expected to be authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct. It's best if you edit your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published declension (linked to the source) that explains why this one is wrong. For further guidance, see How to Answer and take the EL&U Tour.